# Rails, how to determine if a user was created today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like a way to determine if a User record is new or not. Based on where I need to do this in my app, I would like to do this by know if the user was created today or now.

How can I do something like:

```
if current_user.created_at.today?
```

Any timezone issues? Maybe it would be better to do, created_at in the last 24 hours?

Thanks

Comment: Is your requirement for the server side to know if it was created today or the user in their local time?  Timezone would matter in the later case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd rather use `current_user.created_at.to_date == Date.current`, as it is more self explanatory.

Answer (score 8):

To check if the user was created in the last 24 hours, do something like this:

```
if current_user.created_at > Time.now - 24.hours
  #...
end
```

Comment: -24.hours isn't going to work as that could take you into yesterday, instead use:

    Time.now.beginning_of_day

Answer (score 4):

you definitely have several approaches, this is also why I like rails && ruby.
Anyway don't forget about [Demeter Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), hence I will go with the following:

```
class User
  # ... methods and other active record stuff

  def created_today?
    self.created_at.to_date == Date.today
  end

end
```

and than you can see if a user is created today with the following api,

```
 if User.find(params[:id]).created_today?
   #do something...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
 scope :today, lambda {
   where('authdate = ?', Date.today )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs to support time zones:

- Ensure you have the correct time zone set in `config/application.rb`: `config.time_zone = "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"`
- Access the current time: `Time.zone.now`
- Access the name of the default time zone: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[Rails.configuration.time_zone]`
- Retrieve the UTC offset for the default time zone: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[Rails.configuration.time_zone].utc_offset / 1.hour`